# How to override deletion in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I store images in external files while keeping in database records only paths to them. But I want to delete a file if appropriate record deleted.

How should I extend deletion action with file deletion?

Comment: In the service method that calls the delete you could add another method that also deletes the file?

Comment: Of course I can but is this correct?

Comment: Hmm, i think so. Because when you place a transaction around the whole thing if something goes wrong you can always roll back. Skipping some of the problems Peter mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems:

- What if a file cant be deleted? Should the Database-Entry be deleted?
- What if a transaction failed?
- What if a file already has been deleted?

Cant you save the byte-data in the database itself?

Answer (score 0):

You can use hibernate interceptors.

In general you will have to extend EmptyInterceptor and overwrite method in similar form

```
public void onDelete(Object entity, Serializable id, 
    Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, 
    Type[] types) {

    System.out.println("onDelete");

    if (conditionOnFileDeletionIsMet()){
        deleteFile();
    }
}
```

More detailed examples are [here](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-interceptor-example-audit-log/) and [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_interceptors.htm). Documentation is [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/events.html).